# How to get list item's id in unsorted list load by JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The below portion of code works good:

```
<div id="newsListDiv">
  News: <br /><br />
  <ul id="newsList">
    <li id="0">
      News 1
    </li>
    <li id="1">
      News 2
    </li>
    <li id="2">
      News 3
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
  $("#newsList li").click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
  });
</script>
```

But if I comment the UL and I load it via JSON, the script that returns me the id of the list item, seems doesn't work.
Here there is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/tLrjbquq/1/

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when generating elements dynamically.

*General Syntax*

```
$(staticParentSelector).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

*Example*

```
$("#newsList ").on('click', 'li', function () {
    alert("ID --> " + $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/sa9f6kd4/)